# Uncaught TypeError: products.map is not a function, ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, frontend

i want to fetch data from an api and want to display it on page.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import '../all.css';
import Axios from "axios";


const AllProduct = () => {

const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);




const fetchProducts = async () => {

  return await Axios.get(
    "http://localhost:8080/api/QueryAllProducts"

   ).then(res=>{
           setProducts(res.response)
       })
 console.log(products);

}


const display = () => {

  return (products ?? []).map(product => (
    <tr key={product.id}>
       <th>{product.id}</th>
       <th>{product.name}</th>
       <th>{product.area}</th>
       <th>{product.ownerName}</th>
       <th>{product.cost}</th>
     </tr>
   ) );
  
 }
useEffect(() => {
  fetchProducts();
}, []);


  return (
    
    <div>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Area</th>
      <th>Owner Name</th>
      <th>Cost</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {display()}

  </tbody>
  
 
</table>
    </div>
  
  
  )
}

export default AllProduct;
```

i am getting TypeError: products.map is not a function. i did almost every solution which is already present on stackoverflow but i didn't able to resolve my error.In frontend i have used ReactJS and in backend i have used NodeJS

[updated screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFwFD.png)

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` does exactly nothing. You just get back what you had already.

Comment: Doesn't Axios automatically parse the data too? PS: you can't immediately log the result of a state change like that as state changes are batched as an async process. Look into at the [effect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to resolve that.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

  const fetchProducts = async () => {
   return await Axios.get(
     "http://localhost:8080/api/QueryAllProducts"

    ).then(res=>{
            setProducts(res.response)
        })

  console.log(products);
 
}



useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts()
  }, []);
```

or try solution 2:

```
  const [products, setProducts] = React.useState([]);
 
   React.useEffect(function effectFunction() {
       async function fetchProducts() {
           const response = await Axios.get( "http://localhost:8080/api/QueryAllProducts");
           const data= await response.data;
           setProducts(data);
       }
       fetchProducts();
   }, []);
```

Comment: same error after this

Comment: Are the data that comes from backend correct and display them in console?
did u get the data from the backend?

Comment: what is the output when u print data?

Comment: i edit the answer, can u try it and tell me?

Comment: replace this line with your code

Comment: i have attached one screenshot you can see the data that comes from backend

Comment: my error got removed through the first method but still i am not able to display the details on page

Comment: can u share your code on github?

Comment: put "return" word before "await" then try and tell me

Comment: i have updated my code and screenshot here, please check it

Comment: now what is the rest problem

Comment: unable to display data on page

Comment: i can help u if u have a github link and otherwise i can't...beacuse i must look at the code

Comment: can u push the code on github, then i will fix the errors

Comment: okay i will push it, but i think the problem is that i am not getting data in products array

Comment: can u put what is the console when u print response.data" inside then?

Comment: i put solution 2 above, can u try it?, then tell me the result

Comment: my error is resolved thanks

Comment: The data has been filled into products؟

Comment: i will do it for sure once i will get 15 reputation i will do it . Thanks